# A função retorna None apesar da variável guardar o resultado correto

Tags: python, lista, recursão

Devo fazer uma função que retorna os elementos ímpares de uma lista, utilizando recursão. Salvei a lista com os ímpares na variável `I`, e quando retorno essa variável o resultado é `None`.

```
def encontra_impares(lista, indice=0,I=[]):
 if indice >len(lista)-1:
    return I
 else:
    
    testa=lista[indice]%2
    
    if testa != 0:
        I.append(lista[indice])
        
    indice += 1
    encontra_impares(lista,indice,I)
```

Comment: Você não atribui o retorno da função a nada. Tente, por exemplo: `print(encontra_impares(lista,indice,I))` e avalie o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você retornar o resultado da chamada recursiva:

```
def encontra_impares(lista, indice=0,I=[]):
    if indice > len(lista) - 1:
        return I
    else:
        if lista[indice] % 2 != 0:
            I.append(lista[indice])
        indice += 1
        return encontra_impares(lista, indice, I) # <--- aqui

print(encontra_impares([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # [1, 3, 5]
```

Quando você só chama a função (sem o `return`), ela é chamada e o retorno é ignorado, pois você não faz nada com ele (e quando a função se encerra sem encontrar um `return`, ela acaba retornando `None`).

---

Só pra constar, também dá para fazer sem precisar do índice, nem de uma lista acumuladora:

```
def encontra_impares(lista):
    if not lista: # lista vazia
        return []
    if lista[0] % 2 != 0:
        return [ lista[0] ] + encontra_impares(lista[1:])
    return encontra_impares(lista[1:])
```

A ideia é:

- se a lista é vazia, retorna uma lista vazia
- senão, verifica se o primeiro elemento é ímpar

  - se for, retorna ele mais o resultado de `encontra_impares(lista[1:])` (sendo que `lista[1:]` é uma "sub-lista" contendo do segundo elemento em diante)
  - se não for ímpar, retorna somente os ímpares do restante da lista

---

Mas claro que recursão não é a melhor forma de resolver. O mais simples é usando um *loop* mesmo:

```
def encontra_impares(lista):
    impares = []
    for n in lista:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            impares.append(n)
    return impares

# ou usando list comprehension
def encontra_impares(lista):
    return [ n for n in lista if n % 2 != 0 ]
```